# How to get other page after login in node.js by selenium?

Tags: node.js, selenium

I want to crawl score of university homepage.

So I used selenium and succeed to login homepage.

But I can't get "score board page" after login.

What I can do?

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

var hisnet = "https://hisnet.handong.edu/login/login.php";
driver.get(hisnet);

var By = webdriver.By;

driver.findElement(By.name('id')).sendKeys('something');
driver.sleep(4000);
driver.findElement(By.name('password')).sendKeys('something');
driver.sleep(4000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//input[@ src="/2012_images/intro/btn_login.gif"]')).click();

// below code is not working as my think.
driver.sleep(10000);
driver.get("https://hisnet.handong.edu/haksa/record/HREC110M.php");
```

and the error message is below

```
(node:16184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name="id"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.162)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
(node:16184) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:16184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@ src="/2012_images/intro/btn_login.gif"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.162)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
(node:16184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name="password"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.162)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: Is your version of selenium up to date? Looks like it is complaining about an element with `name="id"` not existing, but also warning of using a deprecated interface.

Comment: Chain your calls. Everything is async so make sure the commands execute on known browser states (i.e. don't try to click something when the page that something is in hasn't yet loaded...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason);
  // application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `driver.wait` instead of `driver.sleep` to try again.

You can refer to this article [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-write-reliable-browser-tests-using-selenium-and-node-js-c3fdafdca2a9). Hope this can help you.